# WinMerge: How to compare folder names and file names only, recursively?

Tags: windows, filesystems, winmerge

I currently have two main music folders, one is FLAC, ripped from CD, another is MP3, converted from FLAC. Over the years, my primary MP3 collection (in its own folder) has come from various sources, and has become a mess. I apparently messed up some of the FLAC to MP3 conversions too, and appear to be missing .mp3 files in both MP3 folders.

So, I tried WinMerge to see the differences, but it doesn't appear to be able to compare *folder and file **names only***. It supports recursive folder search, which is nice, but without "names only" filtering, pretty much EVERYTHING looks different when comparing FLAC and MP3 files. I've reviewed comparison options and app preferences and tried looking online, and I've found nothing yet.

Maybe WinMerge isn't the best tool for this, but my attempts with other tools have failed, like with WinDiff. What am I missing, or what should I try?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open CMD/Shell in each of the folders you want to compare.
2. Run `tree /F . > tree.txt` in the CMD, that will export the folder and file structures to a plaintext file named `tree.txt` under dir (If you wanna compare the folder only, just remove the `/F` param).
3. Open WinMerge, compare these plaintext files instead of the concrete directories.

PS:

1. There will be some differences at the head of files, but it is easy to distinguish.
2. Make sure you run the command in the exact directory for comparison, if you get the structure of parent/sub folder, the result of comparison will be in complete shambles.
3. Remember to delete the file after comparing if you don't need it anymore.